# Cannot open the excel file after openpyxl usage

Tags: pandas, openpyxl

I am writing to an excel file in 2 sheets - `sheet1` and `geodata`.

```py
test_df = DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4], 'col2':['a','b','c','d']})
test2_df = DataFrame({'lat':[89.0, 34.89, 23.56],'lng':[45.6, 67.9, 89.0]}, index = ['Paris','Spain','Barcelona'])

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('./test_book.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter') 
test_df.to_excel(writer, 'sheet1')
test2_df.to_excel(writer, 'geodata')
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Later writing to the same file an another new sheet `sheet3` and some additional data to the `geodata`. When I run the below code block and try to open the excel sheet from the folder, I get an error saying it cannot be opened.

```py
test3_df = DataFrame({'col1':[3,5,6], 'col2':['x','y','k']})
test2_new_df =  DataFrame({'lat':[44.6,38.9],'lng':[35.7,89.3]},index=['US','UK'])

from openpyxl import load_workbook

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('./test_book.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = load_workbook('./test_book.xlsx')
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)

test3_df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet3')
test2_new_df.to_excel(writer, 'geodata',header = False, startrow =len(test2_df)+1)
writer.close()
```

When I run this block of code a second time, then I am able to open the file. But I have my new values related to index `'US'` & `'UK'` appended twice in `geodata`. I tried multiple ways but cannot open the file after running this code first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not `import` libraries in the middle of your code. Always `import` at the top of your code. I have copied your code and made one small change of the `xlsxwriter` being the engine, and I am having no issues with the resulting file.

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import *
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4], 'col2':['a','b','c','d']})
test2_df = pd.DataFrame({'lat':[89.0, 34.89, 23.56],'lng':[45.6, 67.9, 89.0]}, index = ['Paris','Spain','Barcelona'])

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('./test_book.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl') #I changed this to openpyxl, from xlsxwriter
test_df.to_excel(writer, 'sheet1')
test2_df.to_excel(writer, 'geodata')
writer.save()
writer.close() 

test3_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[3,5,6], 'col2':['x','y','k']})
test2_new_df = pd.DataFrame({'lat':[44.6,38.9],'lng':[35.7,89.3]},index=['US','UK'])

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('./test_book.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = load_workbook('./test_book.xlsx')
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)

test3_df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet3')
test2_new_df.to_excel(writer, 'geodata',header = False, startrow =len(test2_df)+1)
writer.close()
```

**Output**:

Sheet1: [image: sheet1]

Geodata: [image: geodata]

Sheet3: [image: sheet3]

Comment: Yes @APhillips the change worked. I have seen lot of sample code all started opening a fle with 'xlsxwriter', are the two engines incompatible for same document ?

Comment: That's great. I believe mixing libraries for the same effect is acceptable, but not advised. Both are powerful, but I have a personal preference for `openpyxl`. The issue *could* have been that you assigned `writer` to `xlsxwriter` first, then reinitialized `writer` with `openpyxl`. Please accept my answer with the green check mark if I solved your question.